# how to send tracks between two peers in webrtc

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, webrtc

i'm creating a video calling react app using webRtc and socket.io

the offer and answer are perfectly shared between both peers but i'm unable to send video tracks.

ontrack event listner is not getting fired i don't know what i'm doing wrong here i tried searching about it but i couldn't find any working solution..

```js
import { useState,useEffect,useCallback } from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";



function App() {
  var peer;
  const socket=io('http://localhost:4080/')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [recivingcall,setrecivingcall]=useState(false)
  const [makingcall,setmakingcall]=useState(false)
  const[mystream,setmystream]=useState('')
  const [connected,setconnected]=useState(false)
  const[remotestream,setremotestream]=useState('')
const makecall=()=>{
  console.log("email ",email," room ",room)
socket.emit('join-room',{email,room})

}

const joincall=()=>{

}
const opencamera=()=>{
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:false,video:true}).then(
 async (stream)=>{
setmystream(stream)
const configuration={'iceServers':[{'urls':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]}
 peer=new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
if (peer) {
  const offer = await peer.createOffer();
  await peer.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
socket.emit('sending-offer',offer)
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
  peer.addTrack(track, stream);
});
}

  }
)

}
const creatanswer =async(offer)=>{
if(offer){
  const configuration={'iceServers':[{'urls':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]}
 peer=new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
if (peer) {
  await peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
  const ans = await peer.createAnswer();
  await peer.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(ans));
  socket.emit('sending-answer',ans)
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:false,video:true}).then((stream)=>{
  setmystream(stream)
if(peer){  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    peer.addTrack(track, stream);
  });}
})

}
}
const hendelanswer_recived=async(ans)=>{
  if(ans){console.log(ans)
  const remotedes=new RTCSessionDescription(ans)
await peer.setRemoteDescription(remotedes)
console.log('peer',peer)
socket.emit('connection-complete','ok')
}
}
const hendelconnection=()=>{
  peer.addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
    const [remoteStream] = event.streams;
   setremotestream(remoteStream)})
   console.log(peer.connetionState)
}
   



useEffect(()=>{
  socket.on('room-created',(ev)=>{
   setconnected(true)
   opencamera()
  })
  socket.on('offer-recived',(offer)=>{
    console.log(offer)
    creatanswer(offer)
  })
  socket.on('answer-recived',hendelanswer_recived)
  if(peer){
    peer.addEventListener('icecandidate',event=>{
      if(event.candidate){
        console.log('candidate ',event.candidate)
      }
      else{
        console.log('candidate-notfound')
      }
    })
  
  }
socket.on('connection-complete',hendelconnection)
})
    return (
    <>
    <input id="email" onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}></input>
    <input id="room" onChange={(e)=>setRoom(e.target.value)}></input>
    {connected?<h1>Connecting...</h1>:<></>}
   {mystream &&( <ReactPlayer playing
              muted
              height="100px"
              width="200px"
              url={mystream}
              ></ReactPlayer>)}
    <button onClick={()=>{makecall()}}>makecall</button>
        {remotestream && (
          <>
            <h1>Remote Stream</h1>
            <ReactPlayer
              playing
              muted
              height="100px"
              width="200px"
              url={remotestream}
            />
  
          </>
        )}
        {recivingcall?<button id="joincall" onClick={()=>joincall()}>joincall</button>:<></>}
    </>
    )
  }
  
  

export default App;
```

here is the code of my app .

Answer (score 1):

The session descriptions in WebRTC also describe the data that is shared between the peers. This means you have to add the tracks before creating an offer or an answer.

```js
localstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
localstream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, localstream));
const offer = await peer.createOffer();
await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
```

Additionally if at some time you want to change or add new streams to the connections you will need to renegotiate. Which means to just do the offer answer flow again after adding the new tracks. There is also an event for this on the RTCPeerConnections which triggers if renegotiation is needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/negotiationneeded_event

Comment: i've tried it but it didn't work for me

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference but instead of: "await peer.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));" just do "await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);". The offer is already a RTCSessionDescription. The same also for the answer.

Comment: still not working